# joomla add javascript that changes pictures

Tags: javascript, joomla

i want to write script  that changes picture depending on selected option

```
<img id="image-manekin" src="path_img" />

<select id="form" class="required" name="form">
<option value="red">red</option>
<option value="green">green</option>
</select>
```

and when user clicks on for example red picture is reloaded if nessesary and changed
i looked in varus places but couldn't find answer please help.

Comment: would you be willing to go along with a jquery solution?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail like where is this going? Is it part of a component you're developing or is it something you want to add to an article? What is the outcome you want e.g. is it just the visual display or do you want to store the results like a form submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Joomla specific, because this is just any javascript + HTML.
I implemented this with two click buttons-- you can choose a different way of doing it, but it should give you an idea to start.

Basically, there are two buttons, Red and Blue, and if you click on them, they will swap out the image in the body of the HTML page.  Very simple?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function swapImage(intImage) {
    switch (intImage) {
      case 1:
          img1.src = "http://www.addglitter.com/gr/backgrounds/red/red-0007.jpg"
          return(false);
      case 2:
          img1.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bd/Color_icon_blue.svg/220px-Color_icon_blue.svg.png"
          return(false);
    }
  }
</script>

<img id="img1" name="img1" src="http://www.microsoft.com/library/toolbar/images/mslogo.gif">

<button type="button" onclick="swapImage(1)">Red Image</button>
<button type="button" onclick="swapImage(2)">Blue Image</button>
```

Comment: `LANGUAGE=JavaScript`? come on...really? Have you just copied this from an old forum?

Comment: I copied the template for this javascript function from an existing example, and changed it to fit the questioner's needs.  It doesn't change what happens inside the function either way, but I'll remove the language= bit.

Comment: have edited your answer and removed all the template related tags which aren't needed for Joomla.